# How can I recognize Safari version in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Can I someone recognize version of Safari browser in js or jQuery? I am not looking for webkit version but for version of Safari (for example: 5.1.7).

I need to hide some element for Safari which is less than v7 :(

Comment: safari 5.1 doesn't implement `FileReader` ... but your question is broad ... you say "for example 5.1.7" then say "less than 7" ... use feature detection and don't concentrate on pinning down a version

Answer (score 1):

This hack  worked out by combining multiple other hacks is for 6.1+:

/* Safari 6.1+ (9.0 is the latest version of Safari at this time) */

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) 
and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { @media
{
    .safari_only { 

        color:#0000FF; 
        background-color:#CCCCCC; 

    }
}}
```

Below are hacks that separate 6.1-7.0, and 7.1+
These also required a combination of multiple hacks in order to get the right result:

/* Safari 6.1-7.0 */

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) 
and (min-color-index:0)
{  
   .safari_only {(;

      color:#0000FF; 
      background-color:#CCCCCC; 

    );}
}
```

Here is one for Safari 8 and newer:

/* Safari 7.1+ (9.0 is the latest version of Safari at this time) */

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only {

  color:#0000FF; 
  background-color:#CCCCCC; 

}
```

refer this link:
https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/css-hacks-for-safari-6-1-7-and-8-not-chrome/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if(speechSynthesis){
  //code to be run in Safari 7+
}else{
  //code not to be run in said versions
}
```

This should work, as `speechSynthesis` was added in version 7.

Source: http://CanIUse.com/#compare=safari+6.1,safari+7